# Misunderstanding saturation and supply voltages in OP-AMP's

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

What concept am I misunderstanding in calculating circuit parameters given their supply voltages?

In the following example, the non-inverting voltage is solved with respect to the output voltage, where:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1N7lk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> **KCL @ A:**
>   $$ 0 = \frac{V_{A}-V_{S}}{30k} + \frac{V_{A}-0}{10k} \; \Rightarrow \; \therefore V_{A} = V_{B} = 0.25V_{S}$$
>   **KCL @ B:**
>   $$ 0 = \frac{(.25V_{S})-0}{4k} + \frac{(.25V_{S}) - V_{C}}{28k} \; \Rightarrow \; \therefore V_{C} = 2V_{S}$$

To find the range of values of $V_{S}$ where $V_{C}$ does not saturate, I apply the supply voltages:

$$ V_{C} = 8 \; \text{[v]}= 2V_{S} \; \Rightarrow \; \therefore V_{S} = 4 \; \text{[v]}$$

$$ V_{C} = 12 \; \text{[v]}= 2V_{S} \; \Rightarrow \; \therefore V_{S} = 6 \; \text{[v]}$$

---

However, the solution (and similar solutions) uses a **negative** saturation voltage (-12 [v]) instead of the positive value as drawn in the OP-AMP circuit - resulting in (-6 [v]) as opposed to (+6 [v]).

**Am I misunderstanding sign conventions, or the fundamental application of supply voltages?**

<sup>**For clarity: An edit was made to correct a mismatch between the unedited KCL equations and the circuit schematic - the leftmost 10k resistor was incorrect, and edited to its correct 30k value.  My apologies, but the original KCL equations, given solution, and question remain unchanged.</sup>

Comment: No current can be drawn from the op amp input; it must be drawn from the output through the feedback resistor.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for your interest.  The KCL equations (as written) are correct - no current enters either input terminal.  I am strictly asking about saturation and the V+, V- supply voltages.

Comment: the gain is clearly 4 to 1.

Comment: The supply pin marked '12 v' should be be -12V. Is this error in the circuit diagram the reason you are confused?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thank you, Yes.  I wasnt sure if it was an error in the diagram because Ive seen similar problems also without the '-' signs so I was confused.  It appears my textbook is to blame..? Still, is the lower supply terminal always negative, or is it possible that the negative supply is positive?

Comment: @Andyaka - "the gain is clearly 4 to 1." Huh? Looks like a non-inverting gain of 8 following an attenuation of 1/4, for a total gain of 2. Unless the current schematic has been edited from the original.

Comment: One good way to piss anyone off is to edit a question that then undermines an answer already given. If you want decent help don't do this because as you can see @whatroughbeast is already on my case questioning my math. Please undo your sly correction and live with your error, after all it was my answer that pointed you to correct this. Rewind back to the original or make a substantial effort to make it clear that you have edited your circuit diagram.  I might then consider lifting the down vote I gave you.

Comment: @Andyaka I can acknowledge that in an edit - that said, please note the (unedited) KCL's clearly show how I arrived at the output voltage.  You didnt address that mismatch.  My sincere apology for any inconvenience but I hardly think it degrades the content of the post.  In any case, your answer does not show how the gain is used to calculate the range of voltages within the non-saturated range.

Comment: @Andyaka Edit made: Please note that I cannot revert back to the original, as it contains the original mismatch.  This is the best I can do to correct my mistake.  Regardless, the premise of the question is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is not necessarily your fault, although it would be useful to see a copy of the *original* illustration.

As you seem to have figured out, the 12 volt node is supposed to be -12 volt. Replacing 12 with -12 in your calculations gives the anticipated answer, which means that *you* understand how to do this.

So, why does it say 12 instead of -12? It shouldn't. Maybe you have a bad photocopy of the circuit. Maybe someone copied it wrong. Maybe the PDF isn't correctly rendered.

No electrical engineer would write 12 and then just *assume* that everyone understands that it is supposed to be -12. You might see something like *+/-12*, *±12*, *VEE*, or similar, but the sign is never omitted. Not even if the pin is clearly labeled as being the negative terminal.

A few things makes it immediately obvious that there's something funky with the circuit:

1. Feeding an op-amp with 8 and 12 volts would be pretty unusual, especially so when the inputs and outputs are then referenced to ground. Even worse would be feeding it with 8 and 12 volts in the configuration shown, because the positive voltage is apparently *lower* than the negative.
2. Even *if* you do something like that, any reasonable schematic should have more positive voltages "higher" than less positive voltages. This means that 12 should be above 8. This stops the brain from going crazy when trying to visualize current flow *against* gravity.

Sadly, some textbooks have too many unrealistic circuits, so you can't always assume that it's a misprint. In this particular case, replacing 12 with -12 makes the circuit compliant with my two points, and everything is good. They even use realistic values for the resistors, which is not always true in textbooks. (Voltage divider with 1Ω resistors? Please.)

---

That was the rant+lecture. Now for your question:

> Am I misunderstanding sign conventions, or the fundamental application of supply voltages?

No. There is no secret sign convention. There must be *no* doubt in a schematic diagram. Back in the old days, people sometimes omitted the magnitude for capacitors. For example, they could write `10` and that would implicitly mean `10 µF`. This is still causing great confusion for newbies, and the only reason it's not causing even greater confusion is that 10 farad is not realistic. Don't omit stuff.

I will also answer a question you posted in a comment:

> Is the lower supply terminal always negative, or is it possible that the negative supply is positive?

The "negative supply" can indeed be positive. It would be *unusual*, and the op-amp's "positive supply" must be even *more* positive. All it sees is the difference between its positive and negative supply.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the gain is 4 by purely visual inspection and the opamp will saturate typically within 50 mV of either rail if the op amp was a rail to rail type or within about 1.5 volts of the rails for a standard push pull output. Some op amps like the LM324 will get to within 5 mV of the most negative rail.

I have no idea why you are seemingly making this more complex than it is.

Comment: @theNamesCross, because the gain tells the relationship between output and input. You need to know the gain to know what input voltage will drive the output to the saturation level.

Comment: You need to decide the op amp model and therefore the saturation voltages then divide by 4.

Comment: By inspection the gain is 2.

Comment: @whatrough check the sly edit the op has made

Comment: @Andyaka - Yes indeed. Very sneaky, Sorry to have doubted you.

Comment: This does not answer the question, however trivial: I am asking about sign conventions on the voltage supplies and their restrictions, not how the gain is calculated.  My calculations clearly showed how the gain was calculated - once aware of the (sole) mismatch in the schematic, you downvoted and have not even changed the single relevant digit in your answer (from 4 to 2) to remedy my honest mistake.  You have given no benefit of the doubt before or after my good faith effort - you downvoted for a single error in the schematic, despite all calculations stating otherwise, not on content.

Comment: @theNamesCross get over it and learn the politics.